# Max Noether's $AF + BG$ theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Wikipedia tells me about Max Noether's [$AF + BG$ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AF%2BBG_theorem) but only gives one reference and one external link. I've had a look at the MathWorld link but it seems to be an entirely geometric formulation which I'm not even sure is the same theorem. Does anyone know where I can find an algebraic statement of the theorem, together with a proof? I've tried searching online but the name of the theorem is somewhat unfortunate...

Answer (score 4):

You can find it in Fulton's wonderful book - algebraic curves, available online here:
http://people.reed.edu/~davidp/332/CurveBook.pdf
page 61 (page 69 in the above file).

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a non-geometric proof purely in terms of polynomial manipulations / commutative algebra. I'll have a look anyway, but I'll have to familiarise myself with the notation and the geometry...